# Extending Author-Topic LDA

Tags: topic-model, lda

I've been trying to extend the LDA and wanted some help, direction and insight.

Can Author-Topic LDA be used as a document "category" model? The premise of the Author-Topic model is that multiple authors influence the Topic from which every word is derived. Can I instead treat "authors" as categories to which documents belong?

I've been trying to slightly alter this:

http://yaowu.co/docs/sigir12.pdf

and this

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2994-modeling-general-and-specific-aspects-of-documents-with-a-probabilistic-topic-model.pdf

with Author-Topic model.

What I'm trying to do is find out document-level word associations in the posting-data of a forum on a specialized site. For example, this site is about Candy - its members post about sweets, candy and toffee. Obviously there are categories of candies, then brands and then the products themselves. My reasoning is that if I use Author-Topic and treat the observed node "author" as observed-node "candy categories", then I can introduce that candy category feature into recommender system down the pipeline.

Like the papers above suggest, a "word stream", *switched* by a multinomial 'x' decides which stream a word comes from (background, document or 'candy category').

Do you think this makes sense?

Furthermore, is there a book or resource that, very thoroughly and step-by-step explains the Collapsed Gibbs derivation for LDA?